# Unable to install python library from github

Tags: python, macos, pip

My OS is OSX 10.10.5 and I use Anaconda distribution for python.  I am trying to install the following library from github: https://github.com/gmum/pykernels

When I try to use pip install:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/gmum/pykernels.git
```

I get the following error:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/gmum/pykernels.git
  Cloning https://github.com/gmum/pykernels.git to /var/folders/dd/98c207155h57757dtxkyp44r0000gn/T/pip-x7zo1w22-build
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Conda3/anaconda/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 454, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/dd/98c207155h57757dtxkyp44r0000gn/T/pip-x7zo1w22-build/setup.py'  

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/dd/98c207155h57757dtxkyp44r0000gn/T/pip-x7zo1w22-build/
```

Pip install works well for other libraries and my setuptools is also up to date.

Comment: try `pip install git+https://github.com/gmum/pykernels.git@master` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that library doesn't have a `setup.py` file. pip executes/follows this file. so that library cannot be installed using pip. You can, however, download and put that library (the pykernels folder inside the repo) in your current folder or add it's path to `sys.path` like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("Path to pykernels repo")
```

Be sure to install their dependencies using `pip` like this:

```
pip install numpy scipy scikit-learn
```

Then you can just use `import pykernels` in your script.

**Edit**: `setup.py` is now integrated to the repository and now you can just use `pip`:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/gmum/pykernels.git
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer - setup.py is now integrated with the repository thus one can install directly through `pip install git+https://github.com/gmum/pykernels.git` too

Comment: @lejlot Thank you, added that.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that https://github.com/gmum/pykernels.git does not contain valid installable python package. There is no `setup.py` file in repo root directory but `setup.py` is required to installation.

Answer (score 1):

The repository is missing a setup.py file. Without this *pip* does not know how to install the module/package.

It looks like it's just a plain package without any setup scripts. You'll need to clone it and use it by copy/pasting it into your project or write your own setup.py file.

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/setupscript.html). It's pretty straight forward.