# How do I install xbrl_parser on the server from https://github.com/ONSBigData/parsing_company_accounts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, xbrl

I am trying to Extracting Data from Companies House Electronic Records following the example provided in https://github.com/ONSBigData/parsing_company_accounts.

I run into issues with the installation of xbrl_parser on my server. When I run in terminal pip3 install xbrl_parser or pip install xbrl_parser I get an error.

```
Collecting xbrl_parser
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/72/f8b6d58dfe085a8e9f2b6bf05795f9deb071372d476eb2100f6c0355d803/xbrl_parser-0.1.tar.gz
```

This works but straight after I get:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o3r0rklc/xbrl-parser/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o3r0rklc/xbrl-parser/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-o3r0rklc/xbrl-parser/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-o3r0rklc/xbrl-parser/
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-o3r0rklc/xbrl-parser/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

This is the first time I am trying to install not a major python library, so I am not sure if I need to do something different when getting library from git.

Please advise how to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the distribution: the authors has forgotten to include file `README.md` into the distribution package.

Report the bug to their [issue tracker](https://github.com/ONSBigData/parsing_company_accounts/issues).

Also you cannot install directly from Github: there is no `setup.py` in the repo.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. As recommended I have reported the bug - https://github.com/ONSBigData/parsing_company_accounts/issues/3

Comment: Is there anything else I can do to fix the bug? Can I create my version of the distribution package with the readme file by forking git project? Readdy to do this if the author of the original project does not fix the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I figured a way around distribution bug using the method outlined in - [Unable to install python library from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482104/unable-to-install-python-library-from-github)

So I downloaded GutHub project from https://github.com/ONSBigData/ONSBigData.github.io and copied manually xbrl_parser.py and xbrl_image_parser.py into my current folder (where I have my Jupyter notebook) and it's path to sys.path like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("Path to xbrl_parser.py repo") 
install xbrl_parser as xp
```

suspect this would have worked even without adding path since I copied xbrl_parser.py and xbrl_image_parser.py in the same place where I run my project.